# Projective resolution of $k$ as $k[x]/(x^n)$-module?

Tags: homological-algebra, projective-module

I'm trying to get some familiarity with projective resolutions and therefore working on this little exercise: Find a projective resolution of a field $k$ considered as a  $k[x]/(x^n)$-module (where $x$ acts by zero on $k$).

If $n=1$, this should be easy, as $k$ in this case is isomorphic to the ring $k[x]/(x^n)$ considered as a module over itself. Hence $k$ in this case is free, hence projective.

However, in the case $n>1$, I don't know the answer.

My best attempt is something like  $$0\to (x \cdot k[x])/(x^n) \xrightarrow{\text{inclusion}}  k[x]/(x^n) \xrightarrow{\text{projection}} k\to 0$$ .

This is sequence is exact and the middle term is projective. But I see no reason why $ (x \cdot k[x])/(x^n)$ should be projective. Any advice on this problem would be appreciated.

Comment: It's useful and informative to construct a *free* resolution in this case. I think that every projective module here is free, at least in the finitely generated situation, but anyway, just compute a free resolution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us write $R=k[x]/(x^n)$, and start as you did with the projection
$$ R\to k \to 0.$$

You correctly identified the kernel with $xR$. But instead of using the inclusion $xR\to R$, let us instead use the map $R\to R$ given by $a\mapsto xa$, which has $xR$ as it image. This leads to
$$R\xrightarrow{\cdot x} R\to k\to 0.$$

Now let us keep going: the kernel of the leftmost map is $x^{n-1}R$, since $xa=0$ implies that $xa$ is a multiple of $x^n$. Once again we can use the map $R\to R$ sending $1$ to $x^{n-1}$, which has the correct image. This gives
$$R\xrightarrow{\cdot x^{n-1}} R\xrightarrow{\cdot x} R\to k\to 0.$$

Now something special happens here: the kernel of the leftmost map is... $xR$ again. Can you see how to keep going?

Comment: Oh, yes. Nice. Many thanks. For some reason I assumed that the resolution would be finite.

Comment: What does mean by the phrase $\text{ $x$ acts by $0$}$ ? Is it meaning $x$ acts as $0$ ?

Comment: @M.A.SARKAR Well, yes. It also means $R$ acts through the natural projection $R\to k$ which actually makes $k$ a $R$-algebra, and not just a module.

Comment: @CaptainLama, to be honest, I have lot of confusion with the words $\text{"$x$ acts by $0$"}$. Can you please define in a sentence the words?

Comment: @M.A.SARKAR It means that $k$ is a $R$-module where $x\cdot a=0$ for all $a\in k$. So if $P=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} a_i x^i\in R$ and $a\in k$, then $P\cdot a=a_0a$.

Comment: @CaptainLama, thank you very much. it is nice