# Injective resolution of $K$ as a $K[x]/x^n$-module

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules, homological-algebra, injective-module

I have read about the question here: [Projective resolution of $k$ as $k[x]/(x^n)$-module?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3504403/429077), which deals with a projective resolution of $K$ as $K[x]/x^n$-module, where $K$ is a field. And I am interested in whether the injective case is similar.

> Find an injective resolution of $K$ as $K[x]/x^n$-module, where $K$ is a field and $n\ge 1$.

- As $K\cong K[x]/x$, the case $n=1$ is clear.
- When $n=2$, the ring $R:=K[x]/x^2$ is special as it has Krull
  dimension $0$, which means $R$ is both projective and injective over
  itself. Thus we can consider the following complex: 
  $$0\to
     K\xrightarrow{\cdot
     x} K[x]/x^2\xrightarrow{\cdot
     x}K[x]/x^2\xrightarrow{\cdot
     x}K[x]/x^2\xrightarrow{\cdot x}\cdots$$
  which is clearly exact.

However, I am stuck at the case $n\ge 3$, since there are more than one non-trivial proper ideal then. I am not sure whether a similar trick would work.

Thank you very much in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one such, once you notice that $R=K[x]/x^n$ is self-injective.

$$0\to K\to R\stackrel{x}{\to}R\stackrel{x^{n-1}}{\to} R\stackrel{x}{\to} R\stackrel{x^{n-1}}{\to} R\cdots$$